# Fetch efficiently huge number of entities from DB meeting criteria

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, criteria

Let's say I have about half of million records in table A. Of course table A is joined with table B, C, etc. Now I have to fetch entities from table A which meet my criteria. My criteria consists of about 20-30 rules e.g. name in table A has to be like 'something' or date from table B for joined record from table A with ID=1 should be earlier than today. I see three solutions:

1. Write native query and put parameters from my criteria. But in this case I will join so many tables that it doesn't seem to me as a good example.
2. Fetch all records from table A and then check in Java every rule for each record. But this seems for me as the worst possible solution.
3. Use JPA Criteria. But to be honest I do not know how efficient they are while there are so many records and so many joined tables. What's more it seems to me like working with Criteria can be a little irritating when I have so many rules to match.

Maybe there is another (better) solution to my problem but I cannot see it now. I need to add that I need these fetched entities stored in Java collection because when they are all fetched then I have to work with them (e.g. generate report or create some updates in DB basing on these information).

I hope I described my problem clear and I will be thankful for every tip how to optimize such query.

Comment: Don't worry about the amount of joins. Postgres isn't scared of them. It's also a lot more efficient to do everything needed at the database level and then converting the results to entities, than going back and forth converting results to objects etc. But now you're just guessing instead of testing actual results.

Comment: I would create a native query including all criterias and joins etc. Then let the db do the job, to get as less data as possible returned. Then process them in java. Loading all and then do the filtering by hand will drive you crazy and is error-prone. Using JPA will give you a hough overload and bad performance on that hughe amounts of data, because it deserializes all results in to java objects etc.

Comment: Well I tested all three solutions using simple cases like one rule for two tables with small amount of records. Native query seemed to behave the best from all three mentioned solutions, then Criteria and finally 'matcher' written in Java. But I would like to ask someone who worked with more data so he could suggest something.

Comment: @wawek Well I'm doing work on postgres with tables from a few million to hundreds of millions of rows. It's a lot easier to optimize native SQL and make it easy for JPA, than trying to get JPA to perform complex operations.

Comment: Ok thanks for your fast answers. So as I thought writing a native query would be the most efficient solution but I am a bit afraid that preparing such query for 20-30 rules will look (well how to put that) a bit unprofessionally. At least your answer confirms what I've told to my superiors ;)

Comment: A quick heuristic for this type of question: one of the most expensive things about JPA is the translation from result sets to complex object graphs (lots of memory allocation, result set traversal, etc...) and will often lead to out of memory errors.  You really want to delegate it to the underlying database as most of them are hugely optimized for traversing these types of data sets.  Then it's just a question of how: Criteria or native.  Criteria is more JPA-ish but a bit cumbersome, native binds you to a specific db.

Comment: Better solution not to store entities in collections but try to find whether there is an algorithm which can do the job on streams. For example if you return not an List<TheEntity> but Stream<TheEntity> from your DAO you will be free to partition whole data set on some natural criteria, (date, location, customer, etc). As a result memory consumption would be probably more predictable, fetching and processing will be performed in at the same time. The drawback of this solution is more chatty communication with your db.